# Unable to perform initial svn checkout due to error "Assertion `svn_uri_is_canonical(child_uri, NULL)' failed. Aborted (core dumped)"

Tags: installation, svn, canonical-link

Noob alert... I am fairly new to both Linux and Apache/SVN, so this issue below is likely a stupid user error (stupid referring to both user and error)

Usually I can google my way to a solution, but I have been stumped for a few days on the "conical" error below. There are not many google references to "svn_uri_is_canonical(child_uri, NULL)" that don't also include accessing "error: git-svn died of signal 6" which I did not see

Any advise as to where I should be looking to solve issue below would be greatly appreciated

When I attempt to check out the svn repository that was created during the SVN install I see the following error

```
$ svn checkout http://127.0.0.1/svn/first-repo
Redirecting to URL 'http://127.0.0.1/svn/first-repo/':
svn: /build/subversion-Z4OiCa/subversion-1.13.0/subversion/libsvn_subr/dirent_uri.c:1562: uri_skip_ancestor: Assertion `svn_uri_is_canonical(child_uri, NULL)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Some details about installation

From my Browser, entering "http://127.0.0.1/svn/first-repo/"   displays:

```
first-repo - Revision 0: /
--------------------------------------------------------
Powered by Apache Subversion version 1.13.0 (r1867053).
```

Running svnadmin to check the repo:

```
$ svnadmin verify /var/www/svn/first-repo 
* Verifying metadata at revision 0 ...
* Verified revision 0.
```

From dav_svn.conf (only changes made)

```
Alias /svn /var/www/svn
<Location /svn>

  DAV svn

  SVNParentPath /var/www/svn

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/svnusers

  Require valid-user

</Location>
```

contents of "os-release":

```
NAME="Linux Mint"
VERSION="20.2 (Uma)"
ID=linuxmint
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="Linux Mint 20.2"
VERSION_ID="20.2"
HOME_URL="https://www.linuxmint.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://forums.linuxmint.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://linuxmint-troubleshooting-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.linuxmint.com/"
VERSION_CODENAME=uma
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Apache version:

```
$ apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2021-10-14T16:24:43
```

SVN version:

```
svnadmin --version
svnadmin, version 1.13.0 (r1867053)
   compiled Mar 24 2020, 12:33:36 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

For installation, i followed this guide
https://linuxtechlab.com/simple-guide-to-install-svn-on-linux-apache-subversion/.

I ran into a problem with executing the command:

```
    $ sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-svn libapache2-svn
    E: Unable to locate package libapache2-svn
```

Based on one google result, that package was referred to a "dummy" & not required... not sure if it is related to this issue

I uninstalled and tried again from this guide (very similar instructions with minor differences)
https://www.ubuntupit.com/how-to-install-and-configure-apache-svn-server-on-linux-desktop/

I again ran into a problem with executing the command:

```
    $sudo apt-get install subversion libapache2-mod-svn libapache2-svn libsvn-dev
    E: Unable to locate package libapache2-svn
```

the same conical error still occurs when I attempt checkout

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Read the doc](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.basic) **CAREFULLY**!!!

Who, when, where told you to use for the same svn-PATH both `Location` and `Alias` and even worse, with the same name?!

In assumption, that all prerequisites are met, you have

Start with minimal `Location` section without preceding `Alias`, **don't mix** real pre-existing physical path inside web-server with somehow virtual location (existing `/var/www/svn` in case of server root in `/var/www/` and `/svn` location is very big mistake), use smth. like (move repo accordingly)

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /var/repos
</Location>
```

Test functioning of your (still) dummy system with existing repo (better not as `127.0.0.1`, but with defined in apache's conf ServerName) `http://127.0.0.1/svn/first-repo/`**not** with web-browser or git-svn bridge, but with plain pure CLI svn client

After **successful** checkout of "open" repo, expand configuration by auth-option and re-check **both** (checkout and commit) basic operations

PS: It's *extremely* **The Bad Idea (tm)** to *physically* place repositories inside ordinary web-space, while not prohibited directly it's at least totally insecure

Comment: Thank you. I had added the alias after trying to resolve a different issue and forgot that I had done that. Removing it seems to have resolved the issue.